# How do I insert an element inside two buttons?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have this:

```
<a href="" class="left">Get your prize</a>
<a href="" class="right">Live preview it</a>​
```

and this:

```
a { display: block; float:left; padding:10px 30px; font-size:12px; color: white; text-decoration:none;}

.left { border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;  background:lightgreen; }
.right { border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0; background:darkgreen; }

a:hover { background:red;}
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uKTFk/

Here's my goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LGf1.png << to place the cirlce with "or" text in the middle of the two.

Of course the jsFiddle is not properly styled yet, I'll go on to that later when I solve the problem with "or" circle between the two 'buttons'.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should help:

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="left">Get your prize</a>
<a href="" class="right">Live preview it</a>
<a href="" class="center">or</a>
```

​CSS:

```
a { display: block; float:left; padding:10px 30px; font-size:12px; color: white; text-decoration:none;}

.left { border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;  background:lightgreen; }
.right { border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0; background:darkgreen; }
.center { border-radius: 20px; background:red; height: 15px; width: 15px; 
position: absolute; left: 120px; padding:2px; margin-top: 7px}
a:hover { background:red;}
```

[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKTFk/21/)
    ​

Comment: Wonderful, it worked like charm. I think I was overthinking and overlooked this simple solution. Many thanks!

Comment: Remember to use cross browser support for css3 border radius to avoid ugly-ness: `-moz-border-radius` & `-webkit-border-radius` & `border-radius`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="" class="left">Get your prize</a>
<span style="position:absolute;top:8px;left:126px;">or</span>
<a href="" class="right">Live preview it</a>​
```

Change its positioning then move it to the center using top and left. Offsets are based off of its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your illustration this would work:

HTML

```
<a href="" class="left">Get your prize</a>
<img src="" alt="" class="middle"/>
<a href="" class="right">Live preview it</a>
```

CSS

```
a { display: block; float:left; padding:10px 30px; font-size:12px; color: white; text-decoration:none;}

.left { border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;  background:lightgreen; }
.middle {position: relative; float: left; margin: 5px -10px 0 -10px; z-index: 20;}
.right { border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0; background:darkgreen; }

a:hover { background:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to accomplish your goal (add a `div`):

http://jsfiddle.net/XU7Yq/